# toggle switch on dropdown menu closes the menu

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i have on the menu onClick and onBlur which display/undisplay the menu

```html
<div className="user-nav" onClick={() => setIsDropDownUp((prevInputState) => !prevInputState)}
                      onBlur={() => setIsDropDownUp((prevInputState) => !prevInputState)}>
   <div className={'user-nav__dropdown ' + (isDropDownUp ? 'user-nav__dropdown--up' : 'user-nav__dropdown--down')} >
      <div className="cell">
        <toggle/>
      </div>       
   </div>
</div>
```

i have a toggle switch placed in the dropdown menu
when i click the toggle for some reason it trigger the toggle onClick twice and i want it to not trigger it at all, is there any way to achieve that?
i tried to put event.stopPropagation() on the toggle but now for some reason it triggers the onBlur once and closes the menu
any help is appreaciated! tried to solve this for hours